# Iterate though collection in VB .Net (like it was an associative array!)

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, loops

I don't use .Net unless I have to, and for this project I have to. I like the PHP way of doing things but, it seems I am stuck with using a `Collection` of `Object`'s to store/retrieve the data I need. I have my `Collection` loaded with my `Objects`'s and the code to iterate through the collection, my problem is I am unable to retrieve the "key" as it would be called in PHP (I believe in this case it is actually the name of the object). Consider the following example:

```
            Dim xDoc As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(fName)
            Dim xNav As XPathNavigator = xDoc.CreateNavigator()

            Dim sender As XPathNodeIterator
            sender = xNav.Select("/data/sender/val")
            While (sender.MoveNext())
                SenderInfo.Add(sender.Current.GetAttribute("n", ""), sender.Current.Value)
            End While

            For Each item As Object In SenderInfo
                Dim value As String = item.ToString()
                //need to store the key here
                Dim key As String = Nothing
            Next
```

As you can see, I am navigating an XML document, and creating an `Object` with some Key/Value pairs. The Object would look something like this if it were in JSON:

```
{"name":"John Smith","address1":"123 Anywhere St.","city":"This City","state":"FL"}
```

When I iterate though the Collection I can only get the value of the object, but I need the `Key`, in this instance I want "name","address1","city","state" to be stored in a variable for each iteration.

Any ideas? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for the help, I am truly stuck on this one!

Comment: Where and how exactly do you declare SenderInfo? And is that json sample representative of actual data? Do you have multiple objects like that in the same message?

Comment: I defined SenderInfo as a Collection, I actually just decided to Import System.Collections.Specialized and use a NameValueCollection instead of a standard collection, this allowed me to iterate through the keys themselves (as a Collection does not have a .Keys) So I actually have it worked out. I will write in the solution for anyone else who ever has the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SenderInfo` should be a `Dictionary<String,String>`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx#Y0)'s the documentation and example code, at the bottom, including VB.NET.

Comment: This works as well, I chose a NameValueCollection from the Systems.Collections.Specialized namespace, it is actually an almost exact replica of an associative array! I will choose this as the accepted answer, as It now contains two ways of fixing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be sure right now what you want to do with this code, and that can make all the difference in the world for what I would recommend to do instead.  But it sounds like you really want a class like this:

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class Sender

    Public Property Name
    Public Property Address1
    Public Property City
    Public Property State

End Class
```

And then replace your existing code with something like this:

```
Dim xmlRdr As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Sender))

Using fileStream As New StreamReader(fName)
     Dim mySender As Sender = xmlRdr.Deserialize(fileStream)
End Using
```

You'll probably need a few more attributes in the class to tweak what the deserializer expects the xml to look like. You can read more about serialization here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

Comment: Also a good idea, having a class to handle this will be great in the future, as I am interacting with a proprietary shipping server which I have already written a PHP wrapper for, doing the same for .Net in DLL form is a great idea, Thanks for sharing!